# How to copy text to clipboard using javascript from variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a string:

var mystr = "Hello".

I want to fire an event when clicking on the button that puts the text in the mystr into the clipboard as if they highlighted some text and hit Ctrl+C.

Note that I do not want to involve a text input box.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/400212/6188402).

Comment: @user6188402 That post is referring to using a text input box.

Comment: so post your details code

Comment: @Rolando That duplicate does contain a good answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/277697